# How did this site get out of beta?

Tags: discussion

Ask patents to me appears, whilst possibly useful, to be significantly less healthy and less active than what Stack Exchange typically expects from a site before graduation. How did Ask Patents get out of beta?

Answer (score 4):

Ask Patents was not launched through the normal site-creation process and did not go through the proposal/beta workflow. See:

[AskPatents.com: A Stack Exchange To Prevent Bad Patents](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/askpatents-com-a-stack-exchange-to-prevent-bad-patents/)